# 20.04 boot to megaraid

Tags: 20.04

I have a gigabyte mb with a lsi megaraid pci card with 8 1tb drives in a raid 10. My pc started giving off the hd failed noise.
Before today I had windows 10 and Ubuntu 18 when this happened. I could do a ctrl+? In order to install a virtual cd and change bios settings to boot to it in order to get to the raid config.
Since installing 20.04, it is no longer an option. Everytime I boot my pc it's endless siren with no way to stop it, repair the raid, swap the bad drive with a new one.........

Pull data off while I still can and install 18.04 again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed all bios boot settings to legacy only.
Finally the lsi boot info showed up.
Cntl+H for webbios.
Spammed del to get to setup.
Override boot for raid cd.
Repaired.
Changed all the boot settings back to good config that will boot 20.04 again.
Hopefully remember what I did when the new drives shows up to replace the failing one.